# Apollo GraphQL & AppSync: useMutation doing nothing

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, aws-amplify

I'm trying to use the useMutation hook from `apollo/react-hooks` but there must be something wrong because it just doesn't work (I don't even have an error to work with)

Here is my code :

```
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const CREATE_USER = gql`
    mutation Createuserfromcognito(
        $CognitoUsername: String!
        $UserRoles: [UserRole]
        $UserDetails: UserDetailsInput
    ) {
        createuserfromcognito(
            CognitoUsername: $CognitoUsername
            UserRoles: $UserRoles
            UserDetails: $UserDetails
        ) {
            UserId
            CognitoUsername
            UserRoles
            UserIDCard {
                number
                picture_path
                verified
            }
            UserDetails {
                UserEmail
                UserFirstName
                UserLastName
                UserFullName
            }
        }
    }
`;

const TestPage = (): JSX.Element => {

    const [addUser] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);

    return (
        <div>
            {user.sub}
            <ExchangeRates />
            <Button
                onClick={() => {
                    // API.graphql(
                    //     graphqlOperation(createuserfromcognito, {
                    //         input: { CognitoUsername: 'TEsfsdf' },
                    //     }),
                    // );
                    addUser({ variables: { CognitoUsername: 'TEsfsdf' } })
                        .then(() => console.log('test'))
                        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
                }}
            >
                Test mutation
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestPage;
```

I have tried using the amplify graphql implementation and it works, but I would like to understand why the apollo one doesn't.

When I click the button, nothing happens. No request, no console log.

Do you know where I am wrong ?

EDIT : The thing I find the most weird is that useQuery hooks work fine... So I don't think it is an issue about the authentification, endpoint, etc..

EDIT 2 : In fact the issue was with the combination of AppSync and Apollo as stated in my answer below

Comment: No Apollo provider?

Comment: It is defined elsewhere but as I said in my EDIT useQuery hooks work just fine, so I don't think it is the issue.

Comment: missing values for 2 variables ?

Comment: Use the second array element to get useful information like the errors: `const [addUser, { error, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);`

Comment: Just did that and `{ loading, error, data } = true undefined undefined`. It seems like it is stuck somewhere but I can't find where.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I will update my question but my problem wasn't in fact with Apollo but with the combination of Appsync and Apollo. As stated here : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/448, if you don't set `disableOffline` to true in you Appsync client, mutations will just hang and do nothing.

Here is my new Client :

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: awsconfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
    region: awsconfig.aws_appsync_region,
    auth: {
        type: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
        jwtToken: async (): Promise<string> =>
            (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
    },
    disableOffline: true,
});
```